# Re-throw Throwable from inside callback

Tags: java, spring, exception, aspectj, spring-aop

I am implementing an AOP interceptor which process the logic in `RetryTemplate`. And problem is that `ProceedingJoinPoint#execute` is declared to throw `Throwable`, but `RetryTemplate#doWithRetry` allows to re-throw an `Exception` only. So I have to wrap `Throwable` and then unwrap it back.

My best try looks like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RetryableOperationFailureInterceptor {

    @Around("@annotation(retryable)")
    public Object performOperation(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Retryable retryable)
            throws Throwable {

        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = getRetryTemplate(retryable);
        try {
            return retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context)
                        throws Exception {

                    try {
                        return pjp.proceed(); // throws Throwable
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw e;
                    } catch (Error e) {
                        throw e;
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        throw new RetryWrappedException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RetryWrappedException e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid wrapping or/and catching `Throwable`? The latest is more important for me, as catching `Throwable` trigger a code style violation.

Comment: No you have to catch and wrap it. As `Throwable` isn't declared in the interface. So you cannot ignore it. Also why don't you use the provided [`RetryOperationsInterceptor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/interceptor/RetryOperationsInterceptor.java) but are writing your own?

Comment: @M.Deinum Please post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for pointing out RetryOperationsInterceptor, I will try to use this, it does pretty much the same what I have implemented and handles Throwable in the similar way.

Answer (score 0):

M. Deinum is right, but you do not need to use your own `RetryWrappedException` because AspectJ already offers a `SoftException` (extends `RuntimeException`) for softening/wrapping checked exceptions, but it also works for other `Throwable`s.

Because I found your question interesting, but am not a Spring user, I replicated some of your sample classes as dummies or minimal implementations in order to create a fully working POJO + AspectJ example without any Spring dependency. I also extended the around advice so as to do the retry loop by itself, reading a `maxRetries` value from the `Retryable` annotation. I know it is not 100% your use case, but it illustrates the problem and a few other things:

**Dummy classes/interfaces:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Retryable {
    int maxRetries();
}
```

--

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class RetryContext {}
```

--

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface RetryCallback<T> {
    Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception;
}
```

--

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class RetryTemplate {
    public Object execute(RetryCallback<Object> retryCallback) throws Exception {
        return retryCallback.doWithRetry(new RetryContext());
    }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Random;

public class Application {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Application().performOperation();
    }

    @Retryable(maxRetries = 2)
    public void performOperation() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Performing some operation");
        if (RANDOM.nextBoolean())
            throw new Exception("Operation failed");
        System.out.println("Operation succeeded");
    }
}
```

Without an aspect, there will be no retries and `performOperation()` will randomly either succeed

```
Performing some operation
Operation succeeded
```

or fail

```
Performing some operationException in thread "main" 
java.lang.Exception: Operation failed
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.performOperation(Application.java:16)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:9)
```

**Intercept/retry aspect:**

Now with the following aspect we can

- intercept methods annotated by `Retryable`,
- get the number of maximum retries and
- loop and try joinpoint execution via `proceed()` as many times as specified (`maxRetries + 1` because even if zero retries are requested we call the method at least once).

As you can also see, we use different error handling depending on error type:

- An `Exception` will either be just printed if the maximum number of retries has not been reached yet or re-thrown otherwise, i.e. if the final retry also fails, its the exception will be thrown.
- An Error will always be re-thrown because an error is usually thrown by the JVM and non-recoverable, i.e. in this case there will be no more retries.
- A `Throwable` (should never occur) will be wrapped into a `SoftException` and the latter re-thrown.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.RetryCallback;
import de.scrum_master.app.RetryContext;
import de.scrum_master.app.RetryTemplate;
import de.scrum_master.app.Retryable;

@Aspect
public class RetryableOperationFailureInterceptor {
    @Around("@annotation(retryable) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object performOperation(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, final Retryable retryable) throws Throwable {
        final int maxRetries = retryable.maxRetries();
        System.out.println(pjp + " - maxRetries = " + maxRetries);
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = getRetryTemplate(retryable);
        return retryTemplate.execute(
            new RetryCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= maxRetries; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Retry #" + i);
                        try {
                            return pjp.proceed();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            if (i == maxRetries)
                                throw e;
                            System.out.println(e);
                        } catch (Error e) {
                            throw e;
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            throw new SoftException(t);
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate(Retryable retryable) {
        return new RetryTemplate();
    }
}
```

**Resulting output with active Aspect:**

Immediate success (no retries necessary):

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.performOperation()) - maxRetries = 2
Retry #0
Performing some operation
Operation succeeded
```

Success after retries:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.performOperation()) - maxRetries = 2
Retry #0
Performing some operation
java.lang.Exception: Operation failed
Retry #1
Performing some operation
java.lang.Exception: Operation failed
Retry #2
Performing some operation
Operation succeeded
```

Failure after final retry:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.performOperation()) - maxRetries = 2
Retry #0
Performing some operation
java.lang.Exception: Operation failed
Retry #1
Performing some operation
java.lang.Exception: Operation failed
Retry #2
Performing some operation
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Operation failed
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.performOperation_aroundBody0(Application.java:16)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application$AjcClosure1.run(Application.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.RetryableOperationFailureInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryableOperationFailureInterceptor.java:27)
    at de.scrum_master.app.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:5)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.RetryableOperationFailureInterceptor.performOperation(RetryableOperationFailureInterceptor.java:20)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.performOperation(Application.java:13)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:9)
```